# Elasticsearch: score by distance and return distance without computing distance twice

Tags: elasticsearch

I googled extensively and found to score by distance I need to use `script_score` and to return the distance I need to use `script_fields`, but was unable to find a solution that combined the two queries or shared data between them. So I am computing the distance twice. How can I avoid computing the distance twice and instead compute it only once?

Comment: May I ask what will be inside script_score? is distance the only factor you are using? how about function score?

Comment: I am using several factors. I am using a script_score inside of a function_score: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

Comment: It is not possible as explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681210/how-to-compute-scores-from-script-fields-in-elasticsearch). How about using a decay function in your `function_score` so you don't have to compute the distance again but let it be computed by the compiled Java code of the decay function?

Comment: Val: That answer is in response to a very specific question, which you understand. Thank you for pointing out decay function. I don't think that's quite the same thing (decay is less flexible) and still requires computation at both places.

Comment: @GabeKopley you have mentioned above that you use several factors in computing the score. Could you post some sample query and the response.

Comment: @Sundar: It's under development ;) I did actually end up using the decay for scoring. I'm leaving this question open because it appears to be an arbitrary constraint in ES that there's no way from a `script_score` to add fields to the response  or even just pass state along to pick up from a later `script_fields`. Let's hope that ES someday supports this or somebody comes along with a clever solution.