# Elasticsearch: how to search on computed fields

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

Using the data from the current version of [Elasticsearch: The Definitive Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_indexing_employee_documents.html), that is:

```
[{
    "first_name" : "John",
    "last_name" :  "Smith",
    "age" :        25,
    "about" :      "I love to go rock climbing",
    "interests": [ "sports", "music" ]
}, {
    "first_name" :  "Jane",
    "last_name" :   "Smith",
    "age" :         32,
    "about" :       "I like to collect rock albums",
    "interests":  [ "music" ]
}, {
    "first_name" :  "Douglas",
    "last_name" :   "Fir",
    "age" :         35,
    "about":        "I like to build cabinets",
    "interests":  [ "forestry" ]
}]
```

I'm trying to run a simple computation (I've enabled Groovy scripting) using the request data:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "max_age": {
                        "gt": 150
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "script_fields": {
        "max_age": {
            "script": "_source.age * 5"
        }
    }
}
```

But ES isn't returning any data. How can I search over computed fields? It's even better if I don't need to enable scripting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`script_fields` are computed after the query phase, i.e. [during the fetch phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681210/how-to-compute-scores-from-script-fields-in-elasticsearch), so you cannot reference script fields inside your queries.

What you need to achieve can still be done, though, by using a [`script` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html), like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "inline": "doc['age'].value * factor > max_age",
            "params": {
              "factor": 5,
              "max_age": 150
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of giving max_age as a certain number, can I use something like, 'max_age = doc.field_a.values.max();'

Comment: @M.Prabhakaran it is possible to figure out the maximum value of values in an array within the script itself.

Comment: Can you give me some example?

Comment: @M.Prabhakaran I think you should ask another question as comments are not the proper way of solving problems and showing examples.

Comment: please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346732/how-to-use-maximum-score-of-a-field-in-script-score-elasticsearch

Comment: I'm looking for alternative ways to do it.