# How to use maximum score of a field in script score - ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I'm using ElasticSearch 2.4.0 . Using the script_score, I'm calculating custom score like

```
{"script":"return ( ((doc.field_a.value)* 0.5) + (_score * 0.5) );"}
```

I want something like (some normalisation effect on the field_a value):

```
max_score = doc.field_a.values.max(); 
return ( ((doc.field_a.value)* 0.5)/max_score + (_score * 0.5) );
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Please check on the values api you are calling. I think its returning only a single value